# Is a p-value correction necessary for assessing pairwise location shifts on centered data?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, p-value, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, post-hoc

I am currently assessing whether or not a location-shift can be assumed in non-parametric comparisons to be able to formulate the rejection of the null hypothesis in other terms than the probabilistic index. To do so, I center my data and execute a pairwise two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test on each pair. The data is in some cases unbalanced and not-normally distributed.

Currently I am using this function (in R):

```
pairwise.ks.test<-function (x, g, p.adjust.method = p.adjust.methods, alternative="two.sided",centered=T,...) 
{
    p.adjust.method <- match.arg(p.adjust.method)
    DNAME <- paste(deparse(substitute(x)), "and", deparse(substitute(g)))
    g <- factor(g)
    METHOD <- if (centered) 
    "Pairwise KS test on centered data"
    else "Paiwise KS test "
    compare.levels <- function(i, j) {
        xi <- x[as.integer(g) == i]
        xj <- x[as.integer(g) == j]
        ks.test(xi, xj, alternative=alternative, ...)$p.value
        }
        compare.levels.centered<-function(i,j)
        {
        xi <- x[as.integer(g) == i]-mean(x[as.integer(g) == i],na.rm=T)
        xj <- x[as.integer(g) == j]-mean(x[as.integer(g) == j],na.rm=T)
        ks.test(xi, xj, alternative=alternative, ...)$p.value
    }

if(centered)
     PVAL <- pairwise.table(compare.levels.centered, levels(g), p.adjust.method)
else PVAL <- pairwise.table(compare.levels, levels(g), p.adjust.method)
ans <- list(method = METHOD, data.name = DNAME, p.value = PVAL, 
    p.adjust.method = p.adjust.method)
class(ans) <- "pairwise.htest"
ans
}
```

And at the moment I apply it on my list of datasets without p-value correction:

```
lapply(datalist,function(x)pairwise.ks.test(x$value,x$trt,p.adjust.method="none",alternative="two.sided",centered=T,exact=F))
```

My set has ties and therefore an exact p-value cannot be calculated (hence exact=F). As I only want to assess a possible location shift for each pairwise comparison to be able to formulate rejection of $H_0$ in terms of medians or means in Holm-corrected pairwise Wilcoxon-rank sum tests, should I also apply a (Holm?) p-value correction to assess multiple location shifts?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - doesn't centering remove the very effect you're testing for?

Comment: @Glen_b I center the data to see if there is a location shift: after centering I can use a two-sample KS test to see if data CDFs differ significantly. If they don't that means that there was a location shift (e.g by subtracting a location parameter the CDF's are equal).

Comment: "*If they don't that means that there was a location shift*" -- no, it doesn't necessarily mean that. Unless there's something I missed, your logic is faulty in several ways at once.

Comment: I'm sorry, @Glen_b but I do not see my faulty logic here. $H_0$ is that there is a location shift. i.e. $H0$: $CDF_1$=$CDF_2$ - $\Delta$. If after substracting a location parameter (either median or mean, doesn't really matter under $H_0$) under $H_0$ the CDFs should be the same. Hence they will not be significantly different. Hence you cannot reject $H_0$ in favor of $H_1$. Hence we withold equality of centered CDFs. Hence the location shift assumption holds. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Here's a few problems to get you started: (1) failure to reject doesn't mean $H_0$ (and the other assumptions) are true. That is, if you assume a location shift, subtract an estimate of one, and fail to reject a goodness of fit test, it doesn't lead to the conclusion that it *was* a location shift, it may be only that you lacked power to pick up any other difference. (2) The KS is based on a completely specified distribution. It doesn't have the desired properties when you do what you did. Your nominal p-values don't take account of what you did to the data; they're less likely to reject.

Comment: What do you mean by 'sometimes unbalanced'?

Comment: @Glen_b, thanks that is very helpful. (1) Do you think it  is better to formulate $H_0$ as no location shift? For example $H_0: CDF_1 = CDF_2$, and then run a GOF test? (2) I think I lack the background for this but given that I do not know the underlying distribution of my data beforehand, isn't the empirical CDF the closest match? How can I incorporate my transformations into my p-values? (3) With sometimes unbalanced I mean that in some of the pairwise comparisons unbalancedness may occur while in others not or less.

Comment: (a) If the hypothesis is of a location shift the usual approach is to make no location shift the null (and with reason); (b) If you want power against the location-shift alternative, a goodness of fit test is a poor choice, power-wise; (c) the empirical CDF may be your best estimate of the original CDF\*, but that doesn't mean it's the best way to find a location-shift; \*(perhaps - I bet you know a few things that would narrow the possibilities down)... (d) simulation allows you to examine at both power and the null distribution of whatever you do, under various circumstance; ...(ctd)

Comment: (ctd)... (e) in your (3) what do you mean when you say 'in some of the pairwise comparisons unbalancedness may occur while in others not or less'. You explained what you mean by 'unbalanced' by using the word in your definition. Please explain as if you were explaining it to an intelligent six year old, avoiding undefined terms (like 'unbalanced') as much as possible.

Comment: Oh, and what's a 'probabilistic index'?

Comment: @Glen_b sorry for my tardy reply. (a) very well, let's assume $H_0: CDF_1 = CDF_2$ in further discussion (b) I understand, but I did not know of a more powerfull alternative (c) I don't know where you are getting at here: I have no prior idea about my underlying distribution, that is why I am opting for a non-parametric method. (d) in simulation, you still have to estimate parameters to be able to simulate, right? In some comparisons I do not have a lot of observations (cfr 'unbalancedness'), and hence estimating parameters will be challgenging. ... (ctd)

Comment: (ctd)... (e) I mean that I do multiple comparisons, and hence have to assess multiple location shift hypotheses. In one comparison $n_1$ might be 19 and $n_2$ 21 (n being the number of observations) while in another comparison $n_1$ may be 19 and $n_2$ 8. This is what I mean when I refer to the terms 'unbalanced' and the 'severity' of this 'unbalancedness.' Finally, the probabilistic index is a way to formulate the alternative hypothesis of a non-parametric comparison. It is defined as the probability that one random variable is smaller then the other. $P\{X_i < X_j\}$ so you want. ... (ctd)

Comment: (ctd)... e.g. for the Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test we can define $H_0$ as $H_0: F_1(x)=F_2(x)=...=F_K(x)$ for all x where $F_i(x)$ is the population CDF. The alternative hypothesis is then specified as $P\{X_i < X_j\} \neq 1/2$ for at least one combination of i and j ($i \neq j$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a "general" multiple testing problem to me, since you’re assessing location shift for each of the pairs of datasets? It may lead to a bigger than alpha family-wise false rejection rate and thus a smaller than alpha familywise chance to incorrectly make an interpretation on the mean/median instead of the probabilistic index, which is of course no problem (PI interpretation is of course okay for location shift models also) but may not be what you want to achieve here.

On the other hand, if you choose to apply a multiple testing correction, there may (will) be a tradeoff with the power and thus correcting for the multiple testing may lead you to falsely make interpretations on the mean/median while you should actually be making them on the probabilistic index... I think the easy and safe thing to do here is not apply a multiple testing correction.

Comment: Thanks, @Matt.Vn this was exactly my reasoning. I don't want to loose too much power whilst still being able to express rejection of the $H_0$ in terms of location parameters as the PI is a challenging thing for people to deal with.